# Make g++ create the -o file same as program name

Tags: c++, bash, shell, gcc, g++

I want to write an alias or new command that will call g++ and create an executable with the same name as the cpp file

eg

`g++ hello.cpp` creates `./hello` instead of `./a`

I use `g++ hello.cpp -o hello`

Is there some kind of alias `g++=" g++ $x.cpp -o $x"` that i can create?

Comment: Why not just use a simple `makefile`?

Comment: In fact, even without a `makefile`, invoking `make hello` from within the directory containing `hello.cpp` will probably result in `make` doing the 'right thing' thanks to the [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules).

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what i wanted, btw can you tell me if there is a way to "$x.cpp -o $x" use variables in alias like this?

Answer (score 0):

An alias simply replaces the command with its assigned value. It doesn't execute the assigned value. Think of it like `String command = "assignedValue"`. What you want is a function.

You can execute `function buildCpp() { g++ -o "${1%.*}.out" "$1"; }` and call `buildCpp filename.cpp` to build `filename.out`. You can also add the code to `~/.bashrc` so your custom function is created whenever the terminal is opened.